# How do I install git-imerge on OS X?

Tags: macos, git

Git [imerge](https://github.com/mhagger/git-imerge) looks pretty cool, but the README has no hints for getting it installed.  Is there a quick way to try it out on a mac?

Answer (score 3):

Someone put together a [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) [formula](http://brewformulas.org/GitImerge) so you can

```
$ brew install git-imerge
```

From imerge issues on github, it sounds like this is a [temporary solutions](https://github.com/mhagger/git-imerge/issues/54) and better installation infrastructure and guidance is a [future goal](https://github.com/mhagger/git-imerge/issues/4).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's the same as linux, just put the git-imerge file on your $PATH and make sure it's executable. (You need to have python installed.)

Apparently `git X` looks for an executable called git-X (it's possible that's how git diff, git commit, and all the git commands work: /usr/lib/git-core contains files like git-commit and git-diff --- but they are mostly symlinks to /usr/lib/git-core/git, which I suppose branches on $0).